# django deploy - ubuntu 14.04 and apache2

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

https://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-a-django-app-with-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04/

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBMVVruB9Vs

This was the first time I deploy a website.And these are the tutorials I followed.

Now I can access to the server(by typing 10.231.XX.XX) from other machine and see the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

Then I tried to access my django project. I run:

> python manage.py runserver 8000
>   Validating models...
>
> 0 errors found August 03, 2016 - 09:44:20 Django version 1.6.1, using
>   settings 'settings' Starting development server at
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Then I type 10.231.XX.XX:8000 to try to acess the django page. But I failed. 
It said:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 10.231.XX.XX refused to connect. Search Google for 231 8000 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have tried every thing I can but still can't figure why.
(as followed the website https://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-a-django-app-with-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04/)
I have apache folder in mysite folder, and in override.py:

```
from mysite.settings import *

    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.231.XX.XX']
```

in wsgi.py:

```
import os, sys
# Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.
apache_configuration= os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append(project)

# Add the path to 3rd party django application and to django itself.
sys.path.append('/home/zhaojf1')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '10.231.52.XX.apache.override'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

and __init__py is empty.

in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
WSGIScriptAlias /msa.html /home/zhaojf1/Web-Interaction/apache/wsgi.py

<Directory "/home/zhaojf1/Web-Interaction-APP">
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I have also restart apache after I do everything.

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you switch to nginx. Nginx is recommended stack along with django and uwsgi.

Comment: Any of Apache/mod_wsgi, gunicorn and uWSGI are good options. FWIW, the Django documentation still recommends mod_wsgi. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/ Changing the WSGI server in this case will not necessarily help due to basic errors, plus you just end up with a bunch of new issues to be solved when changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection refused error is likely going to come down to Apache being incorrectly configured for the `VirtualHost` or you accessing wrong port. You also have other basic mistakes in your `wsgi.py` file as well.

Starting with the `wsgi.py` file, the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value is wrong:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '10.231.52.XX.apache.override'
```

The value is meant to be a Python module path. Having the IP address in there looks very wrong and is unlikely to yield what you need.

Next is changes to `sys.path`. The location of your project and activation of any Python virtual environment is better done through options for mod_wsgi in the Apache configuration file.

That you are adding a home directory into the path is also a flag to potential other issues you may encounter. Specifically, the user that Apache runs as often cannot read into home directories as the home directories are not readable/accessible to others. You may need to move the project out of your home directory.

As to the Apache configuration, your `VirtualHost` lacks a `ServerName` directive. If this was an additional `VirtualHost` you added and not the default (first one appearing in Apache configuration when parsed), it will be ignored, with all requests going to the first `VirtualHost`. You do show this as in the default site file, so may be you are okay.

Even so, that `VirtualHost` is set up to listed on port 80. You are trying to connect to port 8000, so there wouldn't be anything listening.

Next issue is the `WSGIScriptAlias` line.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /msa.html /home/zhaojf1/Web-Interaction/apache/wsgi.py
```

It is strange to have `msg.html` as the mount point as that makes it appear as if you are accessing a single HTML page, but you have it mapped to a whole Django project. If you were accessing the root of the host, it also wouldn't map through to the Django application as you have it mounted at a sub URL. Thus perhaps need to use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/zhaojf1/Web-Interaction/apache/wsgi.py
```

Next problem is that the directory specified in `Directory` directive doesn't match where you said the `wsgi.py` file existed in the `WSGIScriptAlias`. They should match. So maybe you meant:

```
<Directory /home/zhaojf1/Web-Interaction/apache>
```

Even then that doesn't look right as where is the `apache` directory coming from. That last directory in the path should normally be the name of the Django project.

One final thing, you may need to change `ALLOWED_HOSTS` as well. If you find you start getting bad request errors it probably doesn't match properly. Change it to `['*']` to see if that helps.

So lots of little things wrong.

Suggestions are:

- Make sure you read the official Django documentation for setting up mod_wsgi. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
- If you are only wanting to do development at this point, use mod_wsgi-express instead. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/using-modwsgi-express-with-django.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/integrating-modwsgi-express-as-django.html